# Converting IBM iSeries DB2 decimal date types into DateTime object

Tags: c#, date, db2

I'm working on a program to import data from an IBM iSeries server into an MSSQL 2008 R2 database. Unfortunately, some developer long ago decided to store dates as a decimal type, effectively breaking the CYYMMDD format being used to store the dates.

For example, in that format, August 1st, 1995 would be stored as: 0950801. However, what's actually being stored in the database is 95081, which obviously throws an exception if I try to convert it to System.DateTime.

If it were a simple matter of missing a leading 0, I could easily add that to the string before trying to convert it. However, there are several (thousands, really) of dates that are only 3 or 4 digits, which I really don't know what to make of. For example, there's a date stored as 1128. I don't know what to make of that at all. If I just tack on 3 leading 0's to that and convert it, it produces an obviously incorrect date.

So, does anyone know a reliable way to parse these dates? Either directly through through SQL select statements, or doing some manipulation in C#? Or am I just to assume 3 and 4 digit dates were never entered correctly in the first place, and just discard such dates?

Comment: Do you know what the dates are supposed to represent? Are they DOBs etc...?

Comment: @Robbie they represent various things, including DOB's, but also transaction dates in customer account history tables. For the transaction dates, I could gustimate the year since obviously a transaction can't exist before our company did, or in the future. But that doesn't work for birthdays...

Comment: I don't think 3 or 4 digit dates are a problem per se given that format. I'd be inclined to import them as-is and deal with it later. Have you seen this? http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-278438/cyymmdd-format-in-db2

Comment: They could just be incorrectly keyed dates or some application could be using that date as a default. Difficult to tell...

Comment: @RobbieDee I have seen that link, and tried what the last person suggested. That does produce correct dates in the 3 and 4 digit dates, it gives dates far in the future for dates stored correctly. I was hoping to avoid a bunch of what (what I consider) sloppy if/else statements to selectively modify the dates, but as far as I can tell, I'm either going to have to do that, or just import them as-is and deal with them at some other point as you suggested.

Comment: Decimal fields don't generally show leading zeros by default.  Your 1128 value is year zero, either 19001128 or 20001128. You may find some of these fields are only 6 digits, with the century inferred by the value and / or the range of valid values for a particular field, such as DOB.

Comment: Yes, if you import everything you can slice and dice it later. If you start dropping, say, customer records for invalid DOB, you'll end up having to drop matching transaction records too. Of course, you could just import the orphan transaction records anyway. It depends on how important referential integrity is to the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal CYYMMDD was a standard IBM format, where C was zero for 1900's and 1 for 2000's.  This dates back to the S/38 (around 1982) or perhaps earlier. But I don't recall seeing them use it prior to the S/38, which was the predecessor to the AS/400 and iSeries.

I suggest creating a user-defined function in DB2 to convert your decimal dates into ISO date values.  DB2 for i will cache results of DETERMINISTIC functions, so the function doesn't have to be recomputed every time it sees a date value it has processed before.

**Update**

Here is an example I adapted to convert a packed decimal(8,0) value in ccyymmd or yymmdd format into a DB2 Date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    Cvt_Dec8cymd_to_Date ( dtin dec(8,0) )
                        returns  date
    LANGUAGE SQL
    CONTAINS SQL
    DETERMINISTIC                           -- caches results
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    NOT FENCED
    SET OPTION DBGVIEW = *SOURCE

prc:   BEGIN NOT ATOMIC                     -- don't rollback on error
          DECLARE ans    date;                                           
          DECLARE cymd   dec(8,0);                                       
          -- add declarations for conditions and handlers here

          SET ans = null;                                                
          CASE                                                           
            WHEN dtin > 999999 THEN         -- more than 6 digits given   
              set cymd = dtin;                                            
            WHEN dtin < 400000 THEN         -- yr < 40 means 2000's       
              SET cymd = 20000000 + dtin;                                 
            ELSE                            -- yr >= 40 means 1900's      
              SET cymd = 19000000 + dtin;                                 
          END CASE;                                                      

          --convert to date                                              
          SET ans = date( insert(insert(digits(cymd),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-') );
          RETURN ans;                                                    
        END prc                                                          
;
```

It is simple logic, without error handling for invalid values.

Someone else may have a better example, or might improve this one.

Comment: That would be great, if you've got the time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the programs (and **particularly any change Comments** [assuming they exist]) that insert / update the Table (Query DB2 for this). The change Comments will hopefully tell you if the **Date format was changed** (e.g. **Y2K**) and why.

Also looking at any program that **read the DB**, there may be **special code** to handle the Date. There may be code to determine the Date Format.

The 95081 could also be an **Ordinal date (YYDDD)** where DDD is the Day of the Year. See [Ordinal or Julian-Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date). These where Dates popular at one stage.

I would guess the DB-Field was originally **YYMMDD** with no Century. The format was probably changed to CYYMMDD for Y2k. Dates like 1128 (and 221) are probably YYMMDD dates that where created before the Y2k changes where Implemented (or where missed in the original y2k implementation and changed later).

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no read/write programs as far as I'm aware. Everyone has been interacting with the database directly via a terminal emulator, which is one reason I suspect incorrect data rather than formatting issues.

Comment: The example was 950801, not 95081.  It appears to be August 1st, 1995.

Comment: @Hg3 Most likely the programs run interactively in the terminal emulator.  If you have (or get) a 5250 emulator, you could log in and look for the program source.  The most common way would be to use the STRPDM command (Start Program Development Manager).  In PDM could work with libraries, then objects in a library (looking for source files), then "members" of the source files.  The source files would most likely be named QxxxSRC, where xxx could be CL, RPG, RPGLE, CBL, CBLLE, or some other program language identifier.  But frankly, this is probably a huge time suck for little gain.

Comment: @Hg3 The programs on IBM i (formerly iSeries) can also be run in background, called "batch".  But trying to find and read source code may be cumbersome if you are unfamiliar with the platform and the programming languages involved, unless you get guidance from the programmers that work on it.  As long as all the date values are explainable in the yymmdd format, which goes for all the examples you've given so far, then you should be all set.

Comment: @WarrenT look at the second paragraph, it clearly states that the date is stored as 95081, hg3 is presuming that it is really 950801. I am just pointing out that 95081 could also be YYDDD date. With out kowing some history / seeing more data it is difficult to tell which it is. If YYDDD was never used at the company it can be saftely excluded as a possiblity.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I think I've found the solution.

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 1,2))  > MOD(YEAR( CURRENT DATE),100)
            THEN DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 3,2), '/'), CONCAT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 5,2), '/')),  CONCAT('19', SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 1,2))))
        ELSE DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 3,2), '/'), CONCAT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 5,2), '/')),  CONCAT('20', SUBSTR(DIGITS(DTPSTD), 1,2))))
        END) AS TransactionDate
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1
```

`DTPSTD` is "Date Posted"

As far as I can tell, this works for any date in 1900 or 2000, but wouldn't work for dates older than 1-Jan-1900. In my case that's fine, since I don't have any dates older than 1920 or so stored.

Comment: See my code for nested INSERT() which turns out to be much simpler than a bunch of CONCAT() and SUBSTR() functions.  Plus you may find `A  || B || C` to be easier syntax than `CONCAT( A, B, C )`