# Create SQL view against AS/400 data

Tags: ibm-midrange

how do I create a view against this table? I want to select according to todays date. BUt the field in the AS400 is defined as Numeric 8 0.

WHat I don't understand is, do I have to recreate the table in Iseries Navigator, this is the Order header and detail. They already exists on AS/400 but never used it in Iseries Navigator. Once the view is created, I should be able to access via crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`CREATE VIEW`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhcview.htm) SQL statement to create the view and convert the numeric date into an SQL date.

Note that if there are any invalid dates in the table will cause an error when you try to select the data.  You may have to include validation logic in the conversion.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT 
    DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(yyyymmdd),1,4) ||'-'||
    SUBSTR(DIGITS(yyyymmdd),4,2) ||'-'||
    SUBSTR(DIGITS(yyyymmdd),6,2)) AS mydate
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, DDS files can be used by SQL and SQL tables and views can be used by RPG.  You won't need to re-create a DDS table in [IBM Navigator for i](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/navigator/) just so you can use it for a view.

Start iNav.  Expand Databases.  Click on your machine name.  Down below, under Database Tasks, you'll see Run an SQL Script.  Double click that.  It will open up a window where you can type in the CREATE VIEW statement JamesA posted.  After you've done that, save the session with File > Save as...  I keep mine in the IFS, and I can easily double click one to bring it back so I can work with it.  I keep all my DDL on the IBM i this way so I can easily re-create my views, indexes, etc.

**EDIT**
If you don't use iNav, consider using RUNSQLSTM and storing your scripts either in a regular source member, or in a stream file directory.  The main idea is that you can write scripts that you can refer back to if you ever need to change something, or perhaps create something similar.

Comment: BUck,I cannot find the database tasks. UNder Management Central it is not there. Under Machine name, there is nothing about databases.

Comment: I added a link to IBM Navigator for i, and added some words about RUNSQLSTM.

Comment: they dont have it installed i checked. only has the basic operations. i have to ask them to install the others. I can try the RUNSQLSTM in meantime, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before you CREATE VIEW, I suggest you CREATE FUNCTION to [perform the date conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428628/converting-ibm-iseries-db2-decimal-date-types-into-datetime-object/16430365#16430365). Using a function not only simplifies syntax for you and others, but the DETERMINISTIC keyword used in the [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428628/converting-ibm-iseries-db2-decimal-date-types-into-datetime-object/16430365#16430365) will cache results, improving performance of the calculation.